# download pdf file from URL using PHP and cookies

Tags: php, pdf, curl, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using PHP for this program. I created a script that login into one website and then go to another page from that website and collect pdf links. That works super cool. For requests, I Use CURL and write cookies in cookie.txt file.

When I take the pdf link this is the URL (newest_invoice_url):

```
https://secure3.billerweb.com/alw/inetSrv?client=701122300&type=ApplicationMenu&authTkn=r7mdbUaDHRqEWm4sbY1q40uvMhNQFjwDVOzhEZaAyFrGMyD0pTgCde/QHTSUf0YrJJw5PThCcAV8O7a2ipV5IZmi7jNGArIZ1ddy-WEJcuNAbMp0VRMnNO9VFCA7s78vwzB9VqCn/Qm5zfyzXH2YoNaqMATofgc3v-SSLYzzV3LGGVlvAF6TPS4JgPbcdxotOwJaGhPsM0qfoBiE74zECNA3o-x9-Amqa-/3Q1cRFUa3LtV77l/mDG1pQP1KbISD27TfSPvG1IgyzOz1BP6n0Ah4WksP95yAMhDUuaViKECBpC4n3n-SdyHyQpXz8UsPS8F3WWwj7aMwFvp2aaHRnP5j3uVl4gRGw1l3ee5BLmhkBZFdB57bcAP2Pinmk4krIuqvzjCZM780j9lMQ7E/lS-KqWQN/zrGF3JOg6CP3HYtna6Ne-XgseIxsf-Ecu7qKfZ-DRCSXtv1ulnn8PW1btvjgUeS-Aia8mo9T3CzUmVnbdkOG0JfrrT9mjHOUevqZb-48776CX9svPxujKVFjHELPX5E8bXzv2yIWyMoHfqpaVm1D2B2BP56GYwD5OQL0a5BNnsEjHBIpMMUCsGAbpXl0bABleBx&unitCode=ALW&keyTkn=W9EqaRvq0FQ_Ij9Nj1zRaPoc88pUKFGSOYlgLKY6qQxuLnHdhQ38Gq8CUviDeObpxvo46fbZ1XRjPTzMc0tTqCphM9Q79QjheglAX2Ay2Gzdo2r0KnRx9gBqoAyKSHk/93tuEmVAbszFdYfP0E-sJRCUWvnNUTDOe6TyEeblIzQ7wEDrNt4nmEI_&slchannel=ALWRSA&enc=web
```

It redirects to another site. I wrote this part of code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = $newest_invoice_url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($data);

preg_match("~Location:\s*(.*)~",$data,$new_link);
if(!empty($new_link[1])){
    echo"\nNew link is \n";
    print_r($new_link[1]);echo"\n\n";
}
```

And it gives me this code:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sun, 12 Jul 2020 20:44:34 GMT
Content-length: 0
Content-type: text/html
Set-cookie: _stkn-hfa3QS7R=Ivqn7zeiy9sFXjnqsO3xxg__; Path=/alw/inetSrv; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
Cache-control: no-store,no-cache,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-security-policy: child-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-ancestors 'self'; img-src * data: https://www.google-analytics.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Location: https://secure3.billerweb.com/alw/inetSrv?sessionHandle=hfa3QS7RCA2EYOpRdKYD4VH3wXUsdfCzuCiEP7ugnN6-xxSNY2w9NzAxMTIyMzAwJlJlcXVlc3RUeXBlPVNob3dQZGY_&client=701122300&type=CompatPresentmentService&action=ShowPdf&firstPage=true
```

And In the Location block, there is new URL that i need, I use the same code and I couldnt save the pdf file in my local, any help?

UPDATE:
First reqeust

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = $newest_invoice_url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie2.txt');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie2.txt');
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($data);
```

Im using the result to get the final redirect link

```
preg_match("~Location:\s*(.*)~",$data,$new_link);
if(!empty($new_link[1])){
    echo"\nNew link is \n";
    print_r($new_link[1]);echo"\n\n";
    $newlink = $new_link[1];
}
```

Second request

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = $newlink;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie2.txt');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie2.txt');
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($data);
```

I receive blank from this second request and i should receive the pdf content

Comment: You can use the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option to have curl automatically follow 30* redirects

Comment: No, I tried to use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, but I only get an error message when I use it, it looks like the session is gone.

Comment: Interesting. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339266/1941241) on a different question, the FOLLOWLOCATION options interferes with the COOKIEFILE setting. Can you try that suggestion of setting the cookiefile to an empty string? If that doesn't work (maybe you need the cookie to get to this redirect url), you're going to have to execute a second curl request manually with the URL you got from `$new_link[1]` (assuming that works?)

Comment: No it doesent works, when I try to write second curl request with $new_link[1] I recived this message: PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to do `curl_setopt()` on something that didn't come from a (successful) call to `curl_init()`

Comment: I tried with an empty cookie string and it still works. Weird. But I cannot recived pdf content still. After I recive Location url from the first curl request I tried the same curl request just with the new url

Comment: If you're re-using the same `$ch` just with a new URL, then you need to remove the `curl_close($ch);` line.

Comment: I receive blank

Comment: Nothing at all? Not even any response headers?

Comment: nothing, blank answer

Comment: That looks good to me, can you `var_dump($newlink);` to verify that it contains the correct new URL? If the URL looks good, then can you try to see if `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` (*after* `curl_exec($ch)` but *before* `curl_close($ch)`) shows anything useful?

Comment: var_dump($newlink); yes link is the same buttt var_dump(curl_error($ch)); shows this text:

Illegal characters found in URL

Comment: Hmm if it's the link from the `Location:` header you posted, there shouldn't be any illegal characters in there. But, your expression might match whitespace or the `\r\n` part at the *end* of the header line as well. Does the result from var_dump($newlink) contain any whitespace? If that's the case, you might be able to set `$source = trim($newlink);`.

Comment: yes, trim helps, but now there is an error

<div class="TitleFont">Operation failed</div>

  <p class="form-style-text">
  If contacting customer support, please quote the above error reference id. You may be able to press the browser Back button to return to the previous screen. Otherwise you may need to login again. We apologize for the inconvenience.
  </p>

Comment: Good (sort of). That means the redirect is now working, but for some reason the remote server won't send you the PDF file. At least you're getting a proper response back now.

Comment: Yes this is the same error that I recive when I use one curl request with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Comment: Ok, but this is an error with the remote server refusing to send you the PDF file. There can be any number of reasons for that, which are really hard to debug remotely. It's usually some kind of check on their side. Maybe your script is moving too fast from getting the invoice URL to trying to download the actual PDF file and they're protecting against this kind of automated downloading, but I've also dealt with situations like this where it turned out I just had to include a Referer header or a proper User-Agent. It's basically trial-and-error at this point to get the download working.